# Sending Notification to two different apps on same device using FCM for iOS

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

2 different apps installed in same device with same firebase project and in firebase separate app is created for each app under same firebase project.Will the Fcm notification work on both apps?

Before spending my time on Development I have searched a lot on it, many Developer reported the latest installed app on that device is only getting notification. IS it true.If so any Solution for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as both of the applications have retrieved a registration token and sent that to your application server and your server will send a message for both tokens, they will receive the message.

Comment: have you tried it, whether it's worked for you?

Comment: Yes, I have had up to five applications under one project and they all received messages just fine.

Comment: for both iOS and android it's working fine? Just confirming . Thank you so much

Comment: Good point, another five applications for iOS, so all together 10 in one project.

Comment: if i subscribe all 5 app with same topic then all 5 will receive same notification?